# Building app with library module cannot find AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

I want to build an Android App with AndroidAnnotations.

Here is a simplified version on GitHub which fails to build/pre-process: https://github.com/aiQon/androidannotationsexample

The app is composed of a main app module and a library module.
Both use AndroidAnnotations (AA). The lib module has a workaround to find the AndroidManifest.xml in debug builds (it refers to the release manifest, because gradle does not build the debug variant for libs).

However, the manifest is found for the library module but not for the main app.
The gradle file of the main app is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.stelle_beratung.androidannotationslibraryexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":mylibrary")
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.2+"
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.2+'
}
```

Gradle complains with:
http://pastebin.com/QZtnHcZD

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to build this simplified project to have a controller Bean in the lib module and reference it successfully in the main app activity by using AA?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Let's move the discussion to [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1254).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since android gradle plugin 14.4, the following line does not work anymore:

`variant.outputs.processResources.manifestFile` or
`variant.processResources.manifestFile`

You have to use this one instead:

`variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile`

Please note if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to use another output (other index than zero).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. Was using Android Studio from the Canary Channel. Going back to Beta solved the issue because I could use android gradle plugin 0.12.2. This solved everything.